# How to change empty *strings to nil using mold package?

Tags: go, reflection

During validation of user input I wanna set to `nil` some empty `*string`s in some structs.

E.g. I have this struct:

```golang
type User {
  Username *string
}
```

If `Username == ""` I wanna set Username to `nil` before proceed.

But I wanna do this using tags, e.g.:

```golang
type User {
  Username *string `mod:"nil_if_empty"`
}
```

because I'm already using this package: https://github.com/go-playground/mold in my project for sanitize.

So I'm creating a custom function to set empty strings to `nil`, but I'm stuck.

**Reproduction**: https://play.golang.org/p/_DlluqE2Y3k

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"

    "github.com/go-playground/mold/v3"
)

var tform *mold.Transformer

func main() {
    tform = mold.New()
    tform.Register("nilEmptyString", nilEmptyString)

    type Test struct {
        String *string `mold:"nilEmptyString"`
    }

    myEmptyString := ""
    tt := Test{String: &myEmptyString}

    err := tform.Struct(context.Background(), &tt)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", tt)
}

func nilEmptyString(_ context.Context, _ *mold.Transformer, v reflect.Value, _ string) error {
    s, ok := v.Interface().(*string)
    if !ok { // ok is always false, why?
        return nil
    }

    if s != nil && *s != "" {
        return nil
    }

    if s != nil && *s == "" {
        // v.SetPointer(nil) // should I use this?
    }

    // v.Set(nil) // how to do this?

    return nil
}
```

1. Why `ok` in `s, ok := v.Interface().(*string)` is always false?
2. How to set `v` to `nil`? Why is `v.Set(nil)` wrong?

*I hope this is a good question to ask on StackOverflow. If not tell me how to improve.*

Thanks.

Comment: 1. That's how mold is implemented, it de-references non-nil pointers.

Comment: Just a thought, I don't know your project, but is it possible that all of this headache can be avoided by replacing a `Username == nil` with `Username == nil || *Username == ""`?  Or making a helper function to do this, e.g.. `isValidUsername(uname *string) bool`.  Maybe the "nilness" of the username is truly uniquely important, or maybe it's not.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I'm using it not only for `Username` but for almost every `*string` in structs. @mkopriva, Oh, I understood this. Is there a way I can change it in its code?